# Windows 8 app with FabricJS Free Drawing Support?

Tags: windows-8, fabricjs

I'm trying to implement free drawing in my windows 8 app but I keep getting this error:

"0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action
   File: fabric.js, Line: 12857, Column: 7"

Adding images to the canvas etc. all works as it does in the demos but in VS when I hovered over "fabric" in this code, fabric.Shadow is not shown as an option in the list:

```
setShadow: function(options) {
      return this.set('shadow', new fabric.Shadow(options));
},
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working for me? I created a build of the api from www.fabricjs.com and included all modules. I've copied the code from the free drawing demo (http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing/) but no joy. I also tried removing any reference to creating a shadow as I don't plan on using that functionality but it still crashes. Thank you

Comment: It was a problem with build files. Should be fixed now. Please try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! It's working for me now. I did have to change the JavaScript provided by the demo to make it work though. Just as a reference to anyone who may want to use it with Windows 8 in future, the jquery code needs to be made more strict for it to update the selectors.

Provided code:

```
var $ = function(id){return document.getElementById(id)};


var drawingModeEl = $('drawing-mode'),
    drawingOptionsEl = $('drawing-mode-options'),
    drawingColorEl = $('drawing-color'),
    drawingShadowColorEl = $('drawing-shadow-color'),
    drawingLineWidthEl = $('drawing-line-width'),
    drawingShadowWidth = $('drawing-shadow-width'),
    drawingShadowOffset = $('drawing-shadow-offset'),
    clearEl = $('clear-canvas');
```

I did away with the above and just used the standard jquery selector $('#drawing-mode') each time I needed it. Then the events were provided as:

```
drawingModeEl.onclick = function() {}



drawingColorEl.onchange = function() {}
```

so I changed the above to:

```
$('#drawing-mode').on('click', function () {});


$('#drawing-color').change(function (){});
```

Now everything works as it does in the demo. Love this API, thank you!